# next-i18nnext Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

suddenly got this warning from nowhere for awhile now, translation works but no idea how to solve this

it gives this warning on wherever I use serversidetranslation

[image]

[image]

I read somewhere which says I should import the config file and pass it to serversidetranslation directly like this
[image]

but I get Cannot find module 'next-i18next.config.js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) as a typescript syntax error

here's what my next-i18next.config.js looks like

[image]
still, the warning remains.
i'm using the nextjs 13.4 and the lastest next i18n